# Machine learning in Azure: How do I publish a pipeline to the workspace once I've already built it in Python using the SDK?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I don't know where else to ask this question so would appreciate any help or feedback. I've been reading the SDK documentation for azure machine learning service (in particular `azureml.core`). There's a class called `Pipeline` that has methdods `validate()` and `publish()`. Here are the docs for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline.pipeline?view=azure-ml-py

When I call `validate()`, everything validates and I call publish but it seems to only create an API endpoint in the workspace, it doesn't register my pipeline under Pipelines and there's obviously nothing in the designer.

My question: I want to publish my pipeline so I just have to launch from the workspace with one click. I've built it already using the SDK (Python code). I don't want to work with an API. Is there any way to do this or would I have to rebuild the entire pipeline using the designer (drag and drop)?

Comment: can talk more about what you expect `Pipeline.publish()` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally empathize with your confusion. Our team has been working with Azure ML pipelines for quite some time but `PublishedPipelines` still confused me initially because:

- what the SDK calls a `PublishedPipeline` is called as a `Pipeline Endpoint` in the Studio UI, and
- it is semi-related to `Dataset` and `Model`'s `.register()` method, but fundamentally different.

`TL;DR`: all `Pipeline.publish()` does is create an endpoint that you can use to:

- [schedule](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-setup-schedule-for-a-published-pipeline.ipynb) and [version](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-setup-versioned-pipeline-endpoints.ipynb) Pipelines, and
- re-run the pipeline from other services via a REST API call (e.g. [via Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-machine-learning-service)).

You can see `PublishedPipelines` in the Studio UI in two places:

- Pipelines page :: Pipeline Endpoints tab
- Endpoints page :: Pipeline Endpoints tab

[image]